# SQL Syntax Error Using WHERE

Tags: php, mysql, sql, where-clause

I'm creating a messaging system for my site and i'm trying to display your friends and i'm having trouble as i'm getting the error:

```
Select Friend: Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT `user_two` FROM `friends` WHERE (`user_one`='2')' at line 1
```

Heres My PHP Code:

```
mysql_connect("************", "*****", "**********");
mysql_select_db("******");

if(isset($_GET['user']) && !empty($_GET['user'])){
   echo "Send Message To " . getuser($_GET['user'], 'first_name');
} else {
   echo "Select Friend: ";
$my_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$friend_list = mysql_query("SELECT `user_one` FROM `friends` WHERE (`user_two`='$my_id') OR SELECT `user_two` FROM `friends` WHERE (`user_one`='$my_id')");
if (!$friend_list) { // add this check.
      die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($run_user = mysql_fetch_array($friend_list)){
    if($run_user['user_one'] == $my_id){
        echo "1";
    } else {
        echo "2";
    }
}
}
```

And heres my friends table structure:

```
`id` int(11) AUTO INCREMENT PRIMARY  
`user_one` int(11)   
`user_two` int(11)
```

I'm trying to get the friends ID and make sure it isn't mine and then display the information i need to, i am a little bit rusty with SQL so just have that in mind.

Comment: Why you using brackets on the where clauses?done

Comment: i thought i should use that @WilliamMadede i haven't really used where statements for checking 2 variables, so thats the trouble im having

Comment: Remove the brackets and run the query again..done

Comment: that fixed it, thanks @WilliamMadede

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the brackets on the inside of the query...done

Answer (score 0):

First, you shouldn't use mysql_.  It is deprecated.  Use mysqli.

Your query is:

```
SELECT `user_one`
FROM `friends`
WHERE (`user_two`='$my_id') OR
SELECT `user_two`
FROM `friends`
WHERE (`user_one`='$my_id')
```

This doesn't make sense.  `OR` is not used to connect two queries.  One solution is to use `union all`:

```
SELECT `user_one`
FROM `friends`
WHERE `user_two` = '$my_id'
UNION ALL
SELECT `user_two`
FROM `friends`
WHERE `user_one` = '$my_id';
```